# Simple MySQL INSERT query on simple InnoDB table takes 40+ms

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, innodb, myisam

I'm wondering what's exact cause that makes insert queries on mysql/innodb to last at least 40ms on machine with fairly strong cpu. "Equivalent" query runs <10ms on same MyISAM table (tables are without any foreign keys). Timings are from MySQL console.

This is "as simple as possible" db structure for reproduction.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table_innodb` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `int_column` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `test_table_myisam` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `int_column` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm running same query from mysql console (which auto-commits transactions in case of InnoDB). No other queries are executed on machine at the time and the results are:

```
 mysql> insert into test_table_myisam (int_column) values (5);
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 mysql> insert into test_table_innodb (int_column) values (5);
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

Is transaction overhead making query to run that longer against InnoDB table? Or?

Comment: ms = milli seconds or minutes?

Comment: How many rows are in the table now, and are you appending to the end of the clustered index or inserting somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Tables are empty prior to test. Freshly created tables and given insert queries gives these timings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three aspects that to be considered with each auto-committed INSERT

## ASPECT #1. Overhead

InnoDB supports MVCC and Transaction Isolation as an ACID-compliant storage engine. In order to accommodate this, a copy of a row before changes are committed is written into the Undo Tablespace section of the System Tablespace file `ibdata1`. What would be written if you are running an INSERT? *A copy of a blank row*. That way, a rollback simply removes the attempt to INSERT. When an INSERT in committed, the copy of the blank in the Undo Tablespace is expunged.

## ASPECT #2. Clustered Index

For every InnoDB table, there exists [**an internal default row index called `gen_clust_index`**](https://serverfault.com/a/239554/69271). This is created regardless of the presence or absence of a PRIMARY KEY. Since your table has a PRIMARY KEY of id, the gen_clust_index is constructed to be associated with the row containing a unique id field.

## ASPECT #3. Configuration

Believe it or not, there are times when MySQL 4.1 out-of-the-box is faster than MySQL 5.5. Sounds shocking, doesn't it? Percona actually benchmarked several versions of MySQL and found this to be the case.

I wrote about this in DBA StackExchange before

- [Why mysql 5.5 slower than 5.1 (linux,using mysqlslap)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/why-mysql-5-5-slower-than-5-1-linux-using-mysqlslap/8385#8385) (Nov 24, 2011)
- [Query runs a long time in some newer MySQL versions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/query-runs-a-long-time-in-some-newer-mysql-versions/6542#6542) (Oct 05, 2011)
- [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968) (Sep 20, 2011)
- [How do I properly perform a MySQL bake-off?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3375/how-do-i-properly-perform-a-mysql-bake-off/3376#3376) (Jun 19, 2011)

Comment: ok, so 40ms is what I should expect in this case? Also, even when I have few insert/update queries within one transaction, timing stays almost the same.

Comment: That would depend on if MySQL is simply out-of-the-box or fully configured. With such a small table, it would be hard to tell.

Comment: I saw the edit, thanks for useful info. But, I'm still under impression that maximum rate of 25 of these inserts per sec even for out-of-the-box MySQL server is ridiculously low. Even if by optimal configuration I get 50% better performance, it's still seeming low...

Comment: That's because 25 blank rows to record in the Undo Tablespace is a drop in the bucket. UPDATEs would be far more noticeable.

Comment: Update query (for example) "update test_table_innodb set int_column = 5 where id = 3" takes even more time (50+ms).

Comment: As I would have expected, `UPDATE` takes more time than `INSERT` because `INSERT` produces a single blank row of overhead, whereas an UPDATE has at least the number of bytes of each column to be changed  per row as the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU is not the factor here. The factor is the disk .
In innodb the command need to be write to log , so if the log disk is the same disk or disk is not fragment or disk is slow than you will have a big difference.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try today later same thing on SSD (this was on rather slow 5k4 hdd).

Comment: I've just tested with SSD and confirmed that bigger factor in query time is disk. With modest SSD, but still with much lower access latency, INSERT query time is significantly lower (~10ms).